# Sphinx : Libstemmer under windows

Tags: windows, sphinx

I want to use the libstemmer library (for french language). It seems that i have to build sphinx with a configure"--with-libstemmer". Then do command "make" and "makefile". How can I build that as I am running under windows?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have the same problem, do you solve it somehow?